# Sending dynamic data to Google Tag manager dataLayer without event

Tags: ajax, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set up some custom tags for Google Tag manager on a website to track some custom data, but it is not tracking. The dataLayer variable is collating multiple data like this in the head above the tag manager code.

The process is, user lands on page, and clicks, this gets the data from wordpress etc using localized data and logs this information via ajax call. We wanted to also log this data in Google Analytics using the tag manager before the ajax call.

Here is the Javascript.

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        console.log(gg_data_object);

        var MyObject = {

            load: function(){
            MyObject._do_ajax('landed', null, null);    
        },

        _readCookie: function (name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return 0;
        },

        _click_trace: function(event){      
            MyObject._do_ajax('clicked', this.href, $(this).attr('class'));         
        },
        _submit_trace: function(event){
            gg_data_object.user_id = MyObject._readCookie('user_id');
            MyObject._do_ajax('submission', gg_data_object.post_type, $(this).attr('class'));           

        },
        _do_ajax: function(event_action, href, class_ref){

            var data = {
                'action'                : 'track_event',
                'security'              : gg_data_object.ajax_nonce,
                'event_action'          : event_action,             
                'current_url'           : gg_data_object.current_url,
                'date'                  : gg_data_object.date_today,
                'phpsessionid'          : gg_data_object.phpsessionid,
                'post_id'               : gg_data_object.post_id,
                'post_type'             : gg_data_object.post_type,
                'referrer'              : gg_data_object.referrer,
                'unique_id'             : gg_data_object.unique_id,
                'user_id'               : gg_data_object.user_id,
                'clickedon'             : href,
                'class_location_type'   : class_ref

            };



            /// Now ping event to google analytics - Nothing works
            dataLayer.push(data);
            dataLayer.push({'gg_event_action': event_action});

            // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
            jQuery.ajax({
                type : "post",
                dataType : "json",
                url : gg_data_object.ajaxurl,
                data : data,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    return true;
                }
            });

        }, 

    }

    MyObject.load();
    $(document).on('click', 'a', MyObject._click_trace);
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', MyObject._submit_trace);

});
```

My issue is not this code above so much its actually the fact that even after spending a day or so reading the documentation, watching videos I cannot seem to set up even one push that works.

In Tag manager:

1. I created a new tag
2. Chose Google Universal Analytics
3. Chose custom event
4. Set up a new macro
5. Gave it a label name say gg_event_type
6. Chose dataLayer Variable

But its not sending the data to Google Analytics.
Any help as to what I am missing would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you define your dataLayer before pushing into it?

Comment: Hi there, do I put this? /// Now ping event to google analytics  
   dataLayer = []; 
   dataLayer.push({
    'event'     : 'gtm_track_event',
    'event_action'    : event_action,    
    'current_url'    : gg_data_object.current_url,
    'phpsessionid'    : gg_data_object.phpsessionid,
    'post_id'     : gg_data_object.post_id,
    'post_type'     : gg_data_object.post_type,
    'referrer'     : gg_data_object.referrer,
    'unique_id'     : gg_data_object.unique_id,
    'user_id'     : gg_data_object.user_id,
    'clickedon'    : href,
    'class_location_type' : class_ref    
   });

Comment: var dataLayer = dataLayer || []; but you really try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: AFAIK when you want to use a custom event in GTM you actually need an "event" key in your dataLayer (and use the value for that key).

Comment: hi There, Yeah I did try that and nothing. dataLayer.push({ 'event' : 'gtm_track_event',  also this is all before the GTM script so checked that too.

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious, how is your rule/trigger set up ? Did you remember to fire your tag with a trigger "event equals gtm_track_event" ?

Comment: Check your datalayer in the dev console as well to verify that your event is there.

Comment: Hi there, Yes I set up a rule/trigger for gtm_track_event, still nought. It must be something very obvious, but what I'm going to try next is to strip it to basics to get an event and "Some" data to fire. Then work up from there. If I solve this, I will post details here of how I resolved this and how it works with localised data from WordPress.

Comment: Are you able to share your site to help with troubleshooting?

Comment: Hi there, OK I got a basic event to fire now. With the standard data. BNut I want to capture more data in this event. dataLayer.push({
    'event'     : 'trackEvent',
    'gtmCategory'   : 'track_event',
    'gtmAction'    : event_action,
    'gtmLabel'    : gg_data_object.current_url }); I am wondering how I can do this without setting up more tags, the tag only seems to capture three pieces of information. What about dataLayer fields?

Comment: Here is what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

OK here so far is what I have done,. I have used the answer button so I can format the answer.

I set up one event as seen, and used this multiple times to track the data using the same reference.

Following this tutorial.

so that is Create a TAG.
Have a custom {{event}}
Set up a macro for label and category
Then created a rule which ties the event in with my custom event reference.

I then

```
/// Now ping event to google analytics      
        dataLayer = []; 
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : event_action,
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.current_url            
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'sessionid',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.phpsessionid           
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'post_id',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.post_id            
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'post_type',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.post_type          
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'referrer',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.referrer           
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'unique_id',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.unique_id              
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'user_id',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.user_id            
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'clickedon',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.href           
        });
        dataLayer.push({
            'event'                 : 'trackEvent',
            'gtmCategory'           : 'track_event',
            'gtmAction'             : 'class_ref',
            'gtmLabel'              : gg_data_object.class_ref,
            /*'event_action'            : event_action,             
            'current_url'           : gg_data_object.current_url,
            'phpsessionid'          : gg_data_object.phpsessionid,
            'post_id'               : gg_data_object.post_id,
            'post_type'                 : gg_data_object.post_type,
            'referrer'              : gg_data_object.referrer,
            'unique_id'                 : gg_data_object.unique_id,
            'user_id'               : gg_data_object.user_id,
            'clickedon'             : href,
            'class_location_type'   : class_ref*/               
        });
        console.log(dataLayer);
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this and set up extra fields but for now this works.
Thanks for all your help.

Andi

Comment: Actually no, that's exactly the way - one may hide this behind some abstraction layer in the code or something, but this is the simplest and thus (IMO) most elegant way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below optimized code. You need to define your action and label in a JSON format and loop through it. Easy to maintain.

```
var dataLayer = [];
var d = [
    {
        'gtmAction' : event_action, 
        'gtmLabel'  : 'gtmLabel'
    },
    {
        'gtmAction' : 'sessionid', 
        'gtmLabel'  : gg_data_object.phpsessionid
    },
    {
        'gtmAction' : 'post_id', 
        'gtmLabel'  : gg_data_object.post_id
    }
];

for(i = 0; i<d.length; i++) {
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'trackEvent', 
        'gtmCategory': 'track_event', 
        'gtmAction': d[i].gtmAction, 
        'gtmLabel': d[i].gtmLabel
    });
}

console.log(dataLayer)
```